# Alternate more than 2 background colors with CSS or JS

Tags: colors, background, css-selectors, alternate

I currently have several `<section>` elements that repeat themselves and I want to assign a 5 different alternating background colors.

Right now I'm using `:nth-of-type(#n)` but I'm almost positive that I'm not using it right and some weird behavior is happening where one of the colors does not repeat through the cycle.

This is an example code:

**HTML**

```
<section>
    <article>This is A1</article>
</section>
<section>
    <article>This is A2</article>
</section>
<section>
    <article>This is A3</article>
</section>
<section>
    <article>This is A4</article>
</section>
<section>
    <article>This is A5</article>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
section:nth-of-type(1n) {
    background-color: red;
}

section:nth-of-type(2n) {
    background-color: orange;
}

section:nth-of-type(3n) {
    background-color: blue;
}

section:nth-of-type(4n) {
    background-color: green;
}

section:nth-of-type(5n) {
    background-color: gray;
}
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?
I would prefer to keep this within the realms of CSS but I do not mind adding JS instructions.

Here's the [JFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eudLg58p/).

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close. Just change your nth-of-type counting to the following.

```
section:nth-of-type(5n+1) {
    background-color: red;
}

section:nth-of-type(5n+2) {
    background-color: orange;
}

section:nth-of-type(5n+3) {
    background-color: blue;
}

section:nth-of-type(5n+4) {
    background-color: green;
}

section:nth-of-type(5n+5) {
    background-color: gray;
}
```

[Here's the JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/or5gj9z5/).